# Holder inequality for multiple sums?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

I've come across Holder inequality used in the below case where $\lambda_i's$ are over some integers and we apply Holder inequality with exponents $2k$ and $2k/(2k-1)$ over the variables $\lambda_1,\dots , \lambda_r$. However, I cannot find a source that states Holder inequality applied over multiple sums. How does this work out here? $J_{k,r}$ is just some counting function and $e(\theta)$ is $\exp(2\pi i \theta)$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some rewriting, we can just apply the usual Hölder inequality. We can indeed just take a single sum over the $r$-dimensional variable $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r)$ taking the values of all possible combinations of $\lambda_1$, ..., $\lambda_r$. Then, to simplify things, we can write:
$$
f(\lambda) := J_{k,r}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r;Z),
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
g(\lambda) := \left|\sum_{x\leq Z} e(\alpha_1x\lambda_1+\ldots+\alpha_rx^r\lambda_r)\right|,
$$
and if we take as you said $p=\frac{2k}{2k-1}$ and $q=2k$, this all just amounts to applying the regular Hölder inequality:
$$
\sum_{\lambda} f(\lambda) g(\lambda)
\leq \left(\sum_{\lambda} f(\lambda)^p\right)^{1/p}
\, \left(\sum_{\lambda} g(\lambda)^q\right)^{1/q}.
$$

Comment: I can see the idea of combining all sums into a single sum for $\lambda$'s in a finite range since the sum is absolutely convergent but would this also work if they can take infinite values?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Yes, this is the proof that $\mathbb{N}\times\ldots\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable. For example if $r=2$ and $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)\in\mathbb{N}^2$, since we can't go through all values of $\lambda_2$ first, we could start with all pairs $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ such that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$, then such that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=2$, then $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=3$, etc. We're going through a finite number of pairs at every step, but we'll still account for all possible pairs. And since the series is absolutely convergent, it doesn't matter what order we sum the terms in.